# Uploading an array of images to firebase storage

Tags: arrays, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an array of images to firebase storage. I have written a function for single image upload and it works perfectly, but i cannot seem to wrap my head around how I can implement image array upload. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction. Below is my sample, and I have kept only the relevant part

```
        uploadAsync = async uri => {
          const user = Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;
          const path = `users/${user}/images/${Math.round(
                  Math.random() * 1000000000
              )}.jpg`;

          return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const file = await response.blob();

            const upload = Firebase.storage().ref(path).put(file);

            upload.on(
              'state_changed',
              snapshot => {},
              err => {
                rej(err);
              },
              async () => {
                const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                res(url);
              }
            );
          });
        };

        updateImage = async ({ image }) => {
          const user = Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;
          for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            const file = image[i].image;
            const remoteUri = await this.uploadAsync(file);
            const firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Images').doc(user);
            firestoreRef.set({
              image: [remoteUri]
            });
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). As explained in the doc:

> The `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that fulfills when
>   all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled
>
> .....
>
> The returned promise is fulfilled with an array containing all the values of the iterable passed as argument (also non-promise values).

Since your `updateImage()` function is an async one, you can pass to `Promise.all()` an array of "calls" to this function (the "iterable" mentionned above) that you generate based on `imageArray` which is an array of `image` Objects (the exact same `image` object you pass to the `updateImage()` function).

So you could do as follows:

```
const updateImageArray = async (imageArray) => {
  return Promise.all(imageArray.map(item => updateImage(item)));
}

const imageArray = [....];

updateImageArray(imageArray).then(urls => {
    urls.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    });
})
```

---

Or in an async function:

```
const urlsArray = await updateImageArray(imageArray);
```

Comment: I am not sure I know where or how to use this, can you be more specific?

Comment: I've adapted the answer. Sorry it was indeed not detailed enough!

Comment: I am getting an error Invalid argument,  can you be kind enough to be more detailed, based on the sample code I have shown in my question, because I think I am not doing it right.

Comment: Where do you get this error exactly? You should keep all the code of your question unchanged and add the code from the answer, which uses the functions declared in your code.

Comment: okay, but the second updateImageArray is not inside any function, and where should const urlsArray = await updateImageArray(imageArray);  be implemented?

Comment: Note that I have recently correct the code from `updateImageArray().then` to `updateImageArray(imageArray).then`. Apart form that, one question: how do you call your function `updateImage` when you want to upload **one** image? Can you share the exact code (please update your question)?

Comment: I import the Firebase like this
import Firebase from './Firebase';


then inside an onpress function, I do the below

Firebase.updateImage({
     image: this.state.imageArray
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Success');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
})

Comment: thats why I am a little confused as to how to implement what you have explained

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205664/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-vincent-o).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue here is that you need to upload every image on its own. A "bundle" upload or similar does not exist.

**The normal approach**

The basic approach to such a propblem would be looping over the array (here array of images `imgArr`) and upload each item individually.
Such a function can look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    this.updateImage(imgArr[i]);
}
```

or with the forEach method:

```
imgArr.forEach((img) => {
    this.updateImage(img);
}
```

***Remember***:
The function this.updateImage is provided in the original code.

Im the case of an asynchronous function like an upload, a fetch of data or other this approach does NOT work. This is caused by the implementation of JS and fact, that the operation inside the for(Each) loop is not possible to await.

The solution comes with the **asyncForEach**. The asyncForEach function executes the asynchronous task (uploading the image) and waits for it to be done.

The implementation works like this (details below):

1. Add the function asyncForEach to your code
2. call the function asyncForEach when uploading the array

**Implementation**
To implement the asynchromous upload do the following:
add the following function somewhere in the upper part of your `.js` file.

```
// implementation of asynchonous forEach   
// array: array of items to process
// callback: the asynchonous function to process the items 
async asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
}
```

to then call the newly implemented function call it with the following lines of code
(**Note**: the variable 'imgArr' represents the array of images to upload):

```
// create a function 'uploadArray' in which the asyncForEach is called. 
const uploadArray= async () => {
    await this.asyncForEach(imgArr, async (img) => {
        await this.updateImage(img);
    };
/* execute the function. The code following this function call will be 
stalled until the images are either uploaded or failed with error 
(implement error handling in the this.updateImage function
await uploadArray()
```

**Ressources**

- [MDN forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Implementation 1](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)
- [Implementation 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)
- [Loops in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: I am not sure I know where or how to use this, can you be more specific?

Comment: Add the function `asyncForEach` somewhere in the code. and when you want to upload the array of images use the second part and replace `imgArr` with your variable name.

Comment: your response is still vague

Comment: take a look now

Comment: Hi Tobias, your approach works and it stores the images in the storage bucket, but while trying to pass it to the firestore, it does not get all the storage url back. it basically replaces each url with the next one. I have updated my post with the latest updateimage.